# Do if statements have their own scope?

Tags: java, scope

I was doing a java exercise the other day and in the exercise we had to get input from the user and then figure out what the max value was and what the average was. We then had to print out those values. Values could only be positive integers and when the user enters a negative integer the program should stop taking in values and not account for that negative integer into the average calculation. My problem was I couldn't figure out a way to compare the current integer entered by the user to the max value.

I just made it's own if statement for it and I was expecting a compile error that the max variable didn't have a value or something like that, but the code worked just fine. So my question is do if statements have their own scope or not? What even has scope in programming and what doesn't.

```java
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      //Create Scanner.
      Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
  
      //Declare and initialize variables.
      double average;
      int sum = 0;
      int num;
      int counter = 0;
      int max = 0;
  
      //Process.
      do
      {
         num = inp.nextInt();
         sum += num;
         if(num > max)
         {
            max = num;
         }
         if(num < 0)
         {
        
            sum -= num;
            System.out.print(max);
            average = sum/(double)counter;
            System.out.printf(" %.2f\n", average);
         }
         ++counter;
      }while(num >= 0);
     
   }
}
```

Comment: "_I was expecting a compile error that the max variable didn't have a value_" - Why? You assigned `0` to the `max` variable.

Comment: Everything in {...} is a block and has its own scope meaning 1. it can see everything in the encompasing scope(s) and 2. variables you define inside the inner scope / block itself are not visible to the outside scope. If it where differently how would your `do ... while` be able to see and modify `num` and `sum`?

Comment: As said you don't get an error because you already declare the variable `max` with an initial value of 0 so there is literally no chance for that variable to not have a value after its declaration. This has nothing to do with scope.

Comment: Did you maybe mistype and meant to talk about `int num;`? because that is a variable you don't immediately give a value when declaring it

Comment: `if` statements kind of create a scope for pattern variables (not the case in posted code, available in newer Java versions) - Java Language Specification [6.3.2. Scope for Pattern Variables in Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3.2)

Comment: If the first number is negative, your code goes into failure: division by 0. You need increment the counter only if valid positive number entered. If num is negative do not add/substract to sum. Calc avg at the end of a cycle only if counter > 0.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help this was so long ago and I have learned a lot more since then. This was when I was first learning how to program and I came across this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do if statements have their own scope?

No, in Java `if` statements do not by themselves create a new scope (until [Java 14](https://www.baeldung.com/java-pattern-matching-instanceof), that is!). However, braced statement blocks (i.e. `{…}`) *do* create a new, nested scope.

However, this is unrelated with your issue, because nested scopes *can* access variables from their parent scope (otherwise most code wouldn’t work). So the following works:

```
int x = 1;

{
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

If `{…}` didn’t inherit the parent scope, that code wouldn’t work.

As noted by Ivar in the comments, your code works because you did initialise the `max` variable to 0 outside the loop.

---

That said, the code can be made simpler and more logical. In particular, the calculation of the average and the output should not be part of the loop but instead happen afterwards:

```
Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
int sum = 0;
int count = 0;
int max = 0;
int num;

do {
    sum += num;
    num = inp.nextInt();
    if (num > max) {
        max = num;
    }
    ++count;
} while (num >= 0);

double average = sum / (double) (count - 1);
System.out.printf("%d %.2f\n", max, average);
```

A commonly used alternative way of writing this loop is using `for(;;)` with `break;`. This variant has the alternative that we can limit the scope to `num` to the loop: it is generally desirable to make variable scope as small as possible, and to initialise a variable at the site of its declaration.

```
…
for (;;) {
    int num = inp.nextInt();
    if (num < 0) break;

    sum += num;
    if (num > max) {
        max = num;
    }
    ++count;
}
…
```